# Java - make sure each letter does not contain a number

Tags: java

Very new to programming, just starting a Java class.
Here is what the assignment says
1.) Input, via a question in the console, the report owner’s first name as a string and build the last name via input, one character at a time. 
a.  Check, conditionally, to make sure the first name and last name don’t contain any numeric characters, numbers between 0 – 9.  If it does you must remove it.  The names can not contain any white space either or special characters.

I already did the first part, and here is my code:

```
package inclassassignment;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inclassassignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println ("Enter your first name");
        String temp; 
        Scanner your_name = new Scanner (System.in);
        temp = your_name.nextLine();
        System.out.println(temp);



        int n = 0;
        System.out.println ("Enter your last name");
        String temp1;
        temp1 = "";
        while (n < 6) {

            System.out.println("Please print the next letter of your last name");
            String nextletter1;
            Scanner lastname = new Scanner (System.in);
            nextletter1 = lastname.nextLine();
            char nextletter = nextletter1.charAt(0);
            temp1 = temp1 + nextletter;
            n++;


        }
        System.out.println(temp1);

        {



        }
    } 


}
```

// I now need to do the part that says to check each ASCII value and make sure none of the letters contain a number. I'm pretty sure this requires an "if else" statement but I've never written one to success.

edit: I should point out I am not allowed to have any static variables or methods in any class except for the class with the main method.

Comment: Take a look at documentation of `java.lang.Character` and specifically note available static methods it has. Although that might be forbidden knowledge for your specific assignment.

Comment: It is wrong to say "none of the letters contain a number".  You mean "none of the characters is a number".  A character can be a letter, or a number, or whitespace, or punctuation, etc.

Comment: *"make sure each letter does not contain a number"* There is nothing to ensure, since a *letter* is a single character (e.g. `A`, `w`, `ü`, etc.), and is by definition not a *digit* (e.g. `1`, `7`, etc.), so it cannot "contain" a number.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that. You understand what I'm saying, though. The string cannot contain any numeric characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your task, you can do it in this way:

```
int n = 0;
System.out.println("Enter your last name");
String lastName = "";

while (n < 6) {
    System.out.print("Please print the next letter of your last name: ");
    String tmp = your_name.nextLine();
    char c = tmp.charAt(0);

    if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
        lastName += c;
        n++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("You can use only letters! Try again!");
    }
}

System.out.println(lastName);
```

Comment: this was more along the lines of what I was looking for. I didn't know "isAlphabetic" was a method. Is there an easy way for me as a beginner to find specific behaviors I am looking for?

Comment: There is the only way - be patient,  inquisitive, motivated and always use a  search before asking. [Is it simple, isn't it?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+character+is+letter)  ;)

Comment: BTW there is a good book for a Java novice - [Head first Java](https://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208)

Comment: I don't see how other than deleting it

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sometimes [reference manuals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and specifications are a lot simpler than you think. In any case, they are definitive and concise so they are good starting points and good for review. (A bonus is an IDE that links from code directly to them.) You can bounce between them and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
String s= sc.nextLine(); //read the string
String regex1 = "\\d+"  // the regular expression for numbers
if(s.matches(regex1))  // check if the string contains numbers
System.out.println("contains numbers");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a utility method to normalize names based on your required rules, [`Character.isUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-) **or** [`Character.isLowerCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase-char-) and a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) over [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) like,

```
static String normalizeName(String name) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : name.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch) || Character.isLowerCase(ch)) {
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then you can call it (and I would use it for both `firstName` and `lastName`, for consistency). Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter your first name");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName = normalizeName(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter your last name");
    String lastName = normalizeName(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.printf("Hello %s %s%n", firstName, lastName);
}
```

Comment: this probably would work but i forgot to point out the edit in my original post.  I am not allowed to have any static variables or methods in any class except for the class with the main method.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is posted elsewhere

`str.matches(".*\\d+.*")`// To check if string contains numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
public String removeNum(String in){
    String[] input= in.split("");
    String num= "0123456789";
    String[] numbers= num.split("");
    List<String> numbersToDelete = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(numbersToDelete.contains(input[i])){
            input[i]="";
        }
    }
    //Converting from Array back to String
    String out = "";
    for(int j=0;j<input.length;j++){
        out=out+input[j];
    }
    return out;
}
```